# update table with primary key , which is used as foreign key in many child tables

Tags: java, mysql

I want to update a table(using mysql)through java.

```
I have a Test table with structure

id(pk)  name address
```

And another tables

```
Practice with following structure

    p_id  id(fk)   branch
```

Now I want to update Test table, but as per foreign key constraints I will get foreign key constraint that

> "Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

" as it is using in child table also.
So how can still update my Test table if I want to update it?

I am trying in this way.

```
UPDATE Test SET  Test.id=1,NAME='XYZ'
```

So should I need to remove foreign key constraints and then update my table as i want and again reapply 
these constraints again?

How should I update my Test table in such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what I understand from your statement`,UPDATE Test SET  Test.id=1,NAME='XYZ'` , is that you are trying to update the primary key as well along with data.

I would suggest do the following if you want to do the above operation.

Algo:

Step 1: Add a new record with new PK
Step 2: update the child with new PK
Step 3: Delete the old record.

```
    insert into test(id,name,address) values(5,'name','address');
          --where 5 is your new PK.

    --Updating the child table
    update practice set p_id=5 where p_id=1 
          --where 1 is your old id in Test.

    --delete the record
    delete from test where id=1
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are trying to do is:

`UPDATE Test SET NAME='XYZ' WHERE id = 1`

If you did `UPDATE Test SET id=1, Name = 'XYZ'`, you would be attempting to set every single test record to `id=1`, and `Name = 'XYZ'`.

The query will no doubt fail because you can't have more than one row with `id=1`.

There will be a foreign key constraint failure if you have a Test record with `id=3`, and you have a Practice record referencing that Test record, and your SQL command is now trying to change all the ids to 1.

Thus, the foreign key constraint fails.

Are you sure you have the correct SQL query?